# Removing a git commit from history

Tags: git

Assume I have the following commits in git

```
A---B---C---D---E---F
```

Also assume that commits `B` and `D` are empty (do not contain files, i.e., empty snapshots).

So, I would like to get rid of `B` and `D`; and I am doing the following:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty
```

And I end up with the following:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F
 \
  \--C'---E'---F'
```

This however is not what I want, I want to end up with

```
A---C'---E'---F'
```

How can I do that?

**Note:** I also tried:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6
```

But still did not work.

---

### Important Update

It turned out I was doing things right. And the aswer from **mu 無** inspired me to investigate more on why it is working for him but not for me. My original branch never was removed. After further investigation, it appears that I had tags in `C` ad `F` that caused the branch to stay. Therefore, before running the `filter-branch` command, I removed both tags and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually ended with the right commits, just do `git checkout F'` now.

In case you have these changes pushed to a remote repository, you will need to force update the branch there using `git push -f origin branch_F':branch_F`.

Sample example:

1. Create a new repo

   ```
   $ git init 
   $ touch a && git add a && git commit -m "added a"
   $ git commit --allow-empty -m "empty 1"
   $ touch b && git add b && git commit -m "added b"
   $ git commit --allow-empty -m "empty 2"
   $ touch c && git add c && git commit -m "added c"
   ```
2. Check the commit history

   ```
   $ git log --oneline
   27196e9 (HEAD, master) added c
   24e10de empty 2
   a2d3931 added b
   88be904 empty 1
   564d4e4 added a
   ```
3. Run filter-branch

   ```
   $ git filter-branch --prune-empty
   Rewrite 27196e9bc27e93ff54ebd10a5c8435e7fe496c78 (5/5)
   Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
   ```
4. Check log for commits again

   ```
   $ git log --oneline
   221f0d0 (HEAD, master) added c
   ab6bf5f added b
   564d4e4 added a
   ```

***EDIT***

As OP mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317300/removing-a-git-commit-from-history/28317697#comment45005767_28317697), this was happening becuase of tags present on intermediate commits. Removing the tags made this work.

Comment: I did the same thing before asking the question, but I still got two branches as described in my question. However, your answer inspired me to find out why I am getting braches (original branch was not removed). It tured out that I have tags preventing the removal. I will update my question to reflect this fact.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it in git but first of all you must make sure that no one has pulled the branch already. if someone did pull it you **CANNOT** and **SHOULD NOT** change the history of the tree.

In case someone already pulled it you will simply need to re-add your "old" content and overwrite the current data.

In case no one has pulled yet here are some of your options:

1. type **`git reflog`** and checkout the last good commit before your changes, you will get a detached head so create a new branch, delete the remote branch and push it again.
2. use **[`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)**
3. **[`git format-patch** <number of commit to choose>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)** and then checkout the branch as described in bullet#1 and apply the desired commit (delete the ones that you wish to skip)

There are more options but those are the simplest one.